# gitlab-runner登録時にERROR: Registering runner... failed status=500 Internal Server Errorとなってしまう

Tags: centos, gitlab

### 発生している問題

gitlabが動いているサーバにて、CI/CD 環境を構築しているのですが、
gitlab-runner登録時に以下のエラーとなってしまい登録ができません。

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner="トークン" status=500 Internal Server Error
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

ネットの情報などを頼りにlogから以下のエラー内容を確認し、発行したトークンの認証に失敗していることは
わかりましたが具体的な解消法などが見つけれていません。
何か解消法について、ご教示いただけませんでしょうか。
ご回答宜しくお願いいたします。

以下logからの抜粋です。

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
This CSRF token verification failure is handled internally by `GitLab::RequestForgeryProtection`
Unlike the logs may suggest, this does not result in an actual 422 response to the user
For API requests, the only effect is that `current_user` will be `nil` for the duration of the request
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

---

### 環境

- OS:Centos7
- gitlabバージョン:12.0.3
- runnerバージョン：12.9.0

Comment: 色々と調べて自己解決しました。
実施した内容について自身の理解が追いついてないため、
理由は調べようと思います。

Comment: beaten-d さん、解決お疲れ様でした。一旦回答をコメントに変換しました（この内容だけだと、同じ問題で困っている方の助けにはならなさそうだからです）。もし理由が分かり次第、改めて新しく回答としてご投稿いただけると嬉しいです =)　あるいは（理由はともかくとして）行った内容の概要を回答として投稿くださるだけでも嬉しいです。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。